# Testdriven.NET for web site or web pages

Tags: asp.net

I'm newbie to unit tests, but I'm trying TestDriven.Net and I'm reading and trying examples of testing functions or methods of classes.

Is there any info how to use it for testing a web site or web pages in ASP.NET? I don't find nothing about that. Thanks

Comment: you can test a controller of a asp.net mvc project.

Comment: Maybe I'm looking in the wrong way. 

Perhaps I should test functions or methods of business layer... is that the correct way?

Comment: Yeah, you can't test your aspx/ascx files - try testing everything below your presentation layer first.